# Google Wallet API to pay 3rd person?

Tags: android, android-pay

Is it possible to use the google's wallet api to pay a 3rd person. For example; I have a product listed in my application and the payment goes to the owner of the product not to me.

To clarify a bit more:

```
             MyApplication
User A -----> Pays to -----> User B
```

Can this be done with Google wallet? Or the only solution available is PayPal's MPL?

Comment: Well, Wallet already provides that on mobile/desktop ("Send Money", "Attach money" in GMail, respectively). AFAIK **APIs** aren't for person-to-person transactions, they're primarily tools for merchants. Technically, you could do that yourself (disburse monies), but you'll have to check on that business model with Google Policy and/or your merchant account provider (depending on which API). Hth...

Comment: This is what I was looking for too. Did you end up going with PayPal's services?

Comment: Nothing, dropped it. I couldn't figure it out.